# passing a cookie as header using request.COOKIES.get('cfrtoken') not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cookies

I have an application which needs cookie information passed headers. When I am passing using

```
 childrequest.add_header('Cookie','cfrtoken=blahblah')
```

It's working as expected.

But when I try to get the same cookie information dynamically its failing.

```
childrequest.add_header('Cookie','cfrtoken= +  request.COOKIES.get('cfrtoken'))
```

I'ts failing. Not sure whats the issue.

I checked `request.COOKIES.get('cfrtoken')` is giving a valid cookie.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a ' after the "=". I don't if that fixes it, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a `'` in `childrequest.add_header('Cookie','cfrtoken= +  request.COOKIES.get('cfrtoken'))`

Should be :

`childrequest.add_header('Cookie','cfrtoken=' +  request.COOKIES.get('cfrtoken'))`